# Pandas remove outliers in a row

Tags: python, pandas

there are tons of questions on removing outliers already but I couldn't solve my problem with them.

I want to remove rows with outliers from the `dataframe`.

Say, I have following `dataframe`:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
a   1   2   3   4   100 2   1   3
b   2   1   3   4   1   2   300 123
c   100 200 300 400 200 500 200 400
```

For row `a` we can assume that 100 is an outlier, so I want to remove `a`.

Even though all the values in Row `c` are high, they are not the outliers for the row itself, so, I want to keep it.

So, basically I want to remove all the rows with outliers.

I tried transposing the DF and did something like

`df = df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < 2).all(axis=1)]`, but it didn't work

Comment: I mean, of course that's not a good definition. I wanted to say that those values for the made sense, whereas if we had that same value in another row it wouldn't make that much sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `axis=1` to `zscore`:

```
df = df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df, axis=1)) < 2).all(axis=1)]
print (df)
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
c  100  200  300  400  200  500  200  400
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `autooptimizer` module, you can easily remove outliers from your dataset. it uses the Interquartile range method to remove outliers

```
pip install autooptimizer
```

and then,

```
from autooptimizer.process import outlier_removal
outlier_removal(data)
```

Comment: Could you please improve your answer by giving information on the algorithms being used or by providing relevant links? To be helpful, you should also add the relevant function calls, not just the imports.

Comment: Yes of course. it uses the Interquartile range method to remove outliers.

from autooptimizer.process import outlier_removal
outlier_removal(data)